# Word Mergebarcode error : "Barcode merge field was not found in header record of data source."

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge, barcode

I'm trying to include some qr codes on some labels but mergebarcode field gives me a headache. The Mergefield displays the URL correctly, but Mergebarcode wont show the barcode giving "Barcode merge field was not found in header record of data source." as error. The URLs are from text fields in Excel, without hyperlink.

On macos 10.14.6 Word 16.41

[merge fields as typed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsWhL.png)

[merge fields in preview and finalized merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJO9S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Word for mac doesn't support `mergebarcode` or `displaybarcode` . You wouldn't find this info on the mergebarcode support page, oh no. [ms support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-mergebarcode-812fc43f-cb53-4782-8f9f-290ed08d34f3)